# securing SAMBA smb.conf best parameters

Tags: security, samba, samba4, fips

given today's date, running **windows 10 or later** and connecting to a **RHEL 8.8 or newer** Linux system which currently has `samba-4.17.5-3.el8_8` what is a ***best practice*** for parameters one should have in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to ensure the **most secure and reliable connection** over that protocol?

Below is what I am using.  Can anyone modify or add to it to make it better?  I am doing a simple samba setup with `security=user` and `passdb backend = tdbsam` withsimple local passwords created with `smbpasswd -a`.  If you have a `smb.conf` template to share that involves windows domain joining and Active Directory and other more complicated things that would be cool too.

I am showing the two basic shares (home and data) that I almost always do, if there are parameters that should also be there to improve security?

note: not concerned all that much with the logging part, but appreciated if you can improve on it or provide explanation such that an admin could read and make a rationale decision on how to configure.

```
# /etc/samba/smb.conf template, RHEL 8.8

[global]
    workgroup = SAMBA
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    load printers = no
    disable spoolss = yes

    log level = 0 vfs:10

    log file = /var/log/samba/sambavfs.log

    max log size = 0

    smb encrypt = required
    client min protocol = SMB3
    client max protocol = SMB3
    client signing = mandatory
    server signing = mandatory

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes
    vfs objects = extd_audit

[data]
    comment = data
    inherit acls = Yes
    read only = No
    path = /data
    directory mask = 770
    create mask = 660
    vfs objects = extd_audit
```

**NOTE:** just also found out that **FIPS=1** in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` (or doing `fips-mode-setup --enable` which is available in RHEL-8) kills a samba connection from windows.  See https://access.redhat.com/discussions/7022626.  This was not the case in RHEL-7.9 when doing FIPS=1.

Comment: "best" makes little sense here – you wouldn't share unix home directories, you wouldn't store passwords in a local database, but rely on LDAP+kerberos/AD for authentication, enroll your users with smartcards, the whole shabang. Generally, what is the "securest for your scenario" is really far too wide a scope, and would still under extensive requirements description be essentially asking for opinionated complete setups.

Comment: maybe I should just power everything off then

Comment: that would be the safest option!

Comment: all i'm asking is what are the handful of parameters that ought to be used in smb.conf... for example if one asked about password security then look in `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` that's where all those relevant settings you need to know about are and then set a number accordingly.

Comment: i didn't think my question would be poopoo'd so quick

Comment: I'm sorry, but security doesn't come from throwing in a "handful of parameters"; otherwise, the default configuration would have been stupid, and this is 2023, software projects and Linux distros have gotten good at shipping sensible default configs. So your question was *bound* to involve architecture for security, and that's just too broad.

Answer (score -1):

for anyone interested, after going through the current man page for samba this is what I pulled out of it that seemed relevant.  With the global section defined below a samba connection from windows 10 works for me to a RHEL-7.9 system (and I assume rhel 8.8+).  Per the man page description I think much of it is default settings but it's nice eye candy knowing what's actually in effect.

```
# /etc/samba/smb.conf
# https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html

[global]
    server role = standalone
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    map to guest = Bad User

#   turn off print stuff
    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    load printers = no
    disable spoolss = yes

#   default deadtime to disconnect after N minutes of inactivity is 10080
    deadtime = 5

    server min prototcol = SMB3_11
    server smb encrypt = required
    server signing = mandatory
#   server smb3 encryption algorithms = AES-128-GCM, AES-128-CCM, AES-256-GCM, AES-256-CCM
#   server smb3 signing algorithms = AES-128-GMAC, AES-128-CMAC, HMAC-SHA256
    server smb3 encryption algorithms = AES-256-GCM
    server smb3 signing algorithms = AES-128-GMAC

    client min protocol = SMB3_11
    client smb encrypt = required
    client signing = required
    client ipc signing  = required
    client protection = encrypt
#   client smb3 encryption algorithms = AES-128-GCM, AES-128-CCM, AES-256-GCM, AES-256-CCM
#   client smb3 signing algorithms = AES-128-GMAC, AES-128-CMAC, HMAC-SHA256
    client smb3 encryption algorithms = AES-256-GCM
    client smb3 signing algorithms = AES-128-GMAC
    
#   client use kerberos = < off | desired | required >
#   kerberos encryption types = < all | strong | legacy >

#   hosts allow = 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
    
    max log size = 0
    log level = 0 vfs:10
    log file = /var/log/samba/sambavfs.log
```

Comment: so while the above `smb.conf` does *work* in rhel 7.9 when doing a `smbpasswd` it will report a handful of unknown parameters.  And in rhel 8.9 just one of those as unknown- `smb encrypt` if I remember.  Also while samba-server will successfully run in linux, the connection from a windows 10 pc will not connect based on some specifically chosen server/client encryption algorithms among a few others.  Murcus I think doesn't approve of this type of info, so if i figure out anything else that seems like a good setting maybe i'll post it maybe i wont.